# TP-LINK TD-W8151N Modem/router as just wi-fi router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, modem, adsl

I am planning to buy TP-LINK ADSL wifi router (model TD-W8151N) for my Internet connection which provides Internet through ADSL telephone line. I am also planning to take cable internet in a few months which provides internet through a LAN cable without the need of any modem.

So I would like to have my modem work for both connections which I am using. When using cable internet I want this TP-Link modem to work just as a wireless router (so that I can have the freedom to use my laptop in different rooms instead of sitting at a place by plugging in that cable). Is it possible to use this modem in that way?

I don't have much knowledge about these things except that I can configure things as instructed. Please suggest me whether I should go ahead and buy this one or if there is any other modem in your view which can serve both my  purposes, let me know.

Operating System I am using: Windows 7

Comment: Most (if not all) ADSL modem + wireless router units cannot be used as just as a wireless router: there is no WAN port.  See similar Q/A http://superuser.com/questions/387188/is-it-possible-to-configure-tp-link-adsl-router-to-work-with-cable-connection/387203#387203 .  Also, not needing a cable modem for "cable internet" seems questionable. Also, one (home/consumer grade) router cannot handle two internet connections.

Answer (score 2):

The TD-W8151N does not have an Ethernet port on its WAN side, so you can't use it to route with anything but ADSL.

You will get a better answer if you explain what you're actually trying to do. Do you have two Internet connections that you use regularly? If so, why? What is the effect you want?

Comment: cost cutting, try to make 2 hybrid devices work as a single separate device each time