# Sharing my broadband connection over a router

Tags: connection-sharing

I have a broadband connection which I can connect to my laptop's ethernet port. If I want to use the same connection on another machine I would have to do it via a router (I dont want to use ICS since it requires both machines to be ON). I have a router but its uplink is a 4p4c pin rather that an 8p8c(RJ45) so my broadband cable wont fit into it. The router I have is ZTE ZXDSL 531B. And the broadband connection I am talking about has an antenna on the rooftop from which an ethernet cable (CAT 5) runs to my PC's LAN port. Is there some way of utilising the LAN ports of the router to achieve what I mentioned above. Please Help

Comment: Instead of being so vague (e.g. only mentioning the connector type), please provide some details like exactly what is the manufacturer and model of this router.  I'm guessing that your "broadband connection" is a cable modem with the typical Ethernet port.  10/100 Base-T only needs 2 twisted pairs, but RJ11 is not a conventional connector for Ethernet, so your mystery router does not seem to have an Ethernet WAN port.  A LAN port certainly won't do what you want.  The lowest cost solution would probably be a ubiquitous wireless router with 4 LAN ports.

Comment: @sawdust Sorry for the late reply. I have edited my question to add router info. (It is ZTE ZXDSL 531B)

Comment: Your "router" is a DSL modem + router unit.  Instead of a cable modem, you have somekind of radio or satellite modem.  A similar Q&A is http://superuser.com/questions/387188/is-it-possible-to-configure-tp-link-adsl-router-to-work-with-cable-connection/387203#387203.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your router has a build in DSL modem as uplink.
You might be able to use your router as a switch if your ISP provides multiple IP addresses.M
If that is the case then just disable the DHCP server on your router and connect the UPlink to one of the pc ports.
If your ISP does not provide multiple IPs then it might still be possible depending on the model of your router, if it supports dd-wrt or any of the other wrt firmwares,  to configure one of the pc ports as an uplink. but that would be rather technical.

Comment: My ISP provides only a single IP. If I connect the UPlink to one of the OC ports on my router without disabling the dhcp, Can you explain what will happen. The dhcp server assigns an IP to my laptop connected to the router as usual but what will happen when it tries to assign an IP to the UPlink?

Comment: Your router will set the dhcp ip for your laptop and not much else will happen. the port where you uplink is conected will not recieve or send anything, since it will be waiting for a dhcp request and your isp will also be waiting for a dhcp request.

Answer (score 0):

A new suitable router instead of your dsl-router is inexpensive. Why not just buy yourself a brand new firewall for ~$100 and be gone with the problem?